# Guzzle: "Header value must be scalar"

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm just trying to implement Guzzle on a new system and I'm getting the following error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Header value must be scalar or null but array provided. in /var/www/html/lvmh/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/MessageTrait.php:191
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request->GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\{closure}(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/lvmh/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/MessageTrait.php(198): array_map(Object(Closure), Array)
#2 /var/www/html/lvmh/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/MessageTrait.php(170): GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request->trimHeaderValues(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/lvmh/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/MessageTrait.php(148): GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request->normalizeHeaderValue(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/lvmh/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Request.php(47): GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request->setHeaders(Array)
#5 /var/www/html/lvmh/Library/Connectors/MySGS.php(114): GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request->__construct('PUT', Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Uri), Array)
#6 /var/www/html/lvmh/Library/Connectors/MySGS.php(139): JST\\Library\\Connectors\\MySGS->send('/integrationsap...', 'PUT', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/lvmh/public/secure/test_m in /var/www/html/lvmh/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/MessageTrait.php on line 191
```

I can't seem to find a single source for what the problem is or how to fix it. In fact, it's almost as if nobody's ever had this problem, because the only references I see to the error message are from the code itself.

Here is a sample of the call that I'm making:

```php
/**
 * Wraps and sends a message with the correct authentication fields in place.
 * @param $uri string The path to the resource we're accessing.
 * @param $method string HTTP method
 * @param $body mixed Any valid JSON-convertible type.
 * @return bool pass/fail
 */
private function send(string $uri, string $method, $body): bool
{
    if ($this->getTokenValid()) {
        $options = [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization'             => sprintf("Bearer %s", $this->token),
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
                'Content-Type'              => 'application/json'
            ],
            'body' => $body
        ];
        $request = new Request($method, $uri, $options);
        try {
            $req = $this->client->send($request);
            return $req->getReasonPhrase();
        } catch (ClientErrorResponseException $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        error_log('Not authenticated');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Based on my own research, I've discovered that the class MessageTrait is generating this error message when trying to create the headers. But what's happening doesn't make much sense. If I send an empty array, I get an error message (line 167 of the class) "'Header value can not be an empty array.'" However, when I pass an array of strings, it gives me the above error message. Based on the function normalizeHeaderValue(), even were I to pass a single string in, it would convert that value to an array, so clearly, the code wants an array.

I'm confused. Anybody have an idea what is going on?

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($options)` on a request where you get this error?

Comment: your guzzle version?

Comment: check the type of `SUBSCRIPTION_ID` is it string only in every cases

Comment: @Cully Good idea, but its looks right: a bunch of strings.

Comment: @bhucho "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2"

Comment: @bhucho Good idea as well. The subscription ID is all alphanumeric.

Comment: use on_stats & debug as true to check what is actually sent

Comment: @ThomasBelknap Could you paste into your question the output of `var_dump($options)` on a request where you get this error? Also, there's a chance that the response header is somehow being parsed into a non-scalar. Have you tried making the request with something like [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) and seeing what it responds with?

Comment: @Cully thanks! I ended up going in another direction because it wasn't working. However as you can see from the code above, the $options are being set explicitly every call, so there is no "where you get this error." It's every one.

Comment: @Cully is there a way that I can tell whether the system is choking on the request or the response? The error isn't clear, now that you mention it?

Comment: @ThomasBelknap See my previous comment.

Comment: @ThomasBelknap Also, you can look at the code in the stacktrace you provided and see if it's being thrown on the request or the response. You can also edit the code itself and `vardump` values along the way to see what it's getting.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Turned on debugging and getting a lot more information. Now I'm trying to use put() and having other issues. But that's for another post.

Answer (score 1):

The Guzzle request object does not accept an $options parameter. You are creating an instance of Request as:

```
    $request = new Request($method, $uri, $options);
```

But it should be:

```
    $request = new Request($method, $uri, $headers, $body);
```

The error you're getting is caused by the fact that Guzzle is trying to parse $body as if it were a header. Because it's definitely not a header (but an array instead), it struggles to normalize it as if it were a header.